# Recursive method to solve text file

Tags: c#, recursion

In C# I get a dictionary `dict` after reading in a text file that looks kind of like this

```
#33=CLOSED_SHELL('',(#34,#35,#36,#37,#38,#39));
#34=ADVANCED_FACE('',(#46),#40,.F.);
#35=ADVANCED_FACE('',(#47),#41,.F.);
#36=ADVANCED_FACE('',(#48),#42,.F.);
#37=ADVANCED_FACE('',(#49),#43,.F.);
#38=ADVANCED_FACE('',(#50),#44,.T.);
#39=ADVANCED_FACE('',(#51),#45,.F.);
#40=PLANE('',#127);
#41=PLANE('',#128);
#42=PLANE('',#129);
#43=PLANE('',#130);
#44=PLANE('',#131);
#45=PLANE('',#132);
#46=FACE_OUTER_BOUND('',#52,.T.);
#47=FACE_OUTER_BOUND('',#53,.T.);
#48=FACE_OUTER_BOUND('',#54,.T.);
#49=FACE_OUTER_BOUND('',#55,.T.);
#50=FACE_OUTER_BOUND('',#56,.T.);
#51=FACE_OUTER_BOUND('',#57,.T.);
#52=EDGE_LOOP('',(#58,#59,#60,#61));
#53=EDGE_LOOP('',(#62,#63,#64,#65));
#54=EDGE_LOOP('',(#66,#67,#68,#69));
#55=EDGE_LOOP('',(#70,#71,#72,#73));
#56=EDGE_LOOP('',(#74,#75,#76,#77));
#57=EDGE_LOOP('',(#78,#79,#80,#81));
//... this goes on for a couple of other elements
```

As you can see each line contains multiple references for another line. Each reference # at the beginning is unique so these are the keys in `dict`.
So I'm using this method to solve each category step by step:

```
 private void RecursiveMethod(Dictionary<string, string> dict, Step stepObj, List<List<string>> getList, Action<List<string>> setList)
    {

        foreach(var item in getList.ToList())
        {
            for(int valuesIndex = 1; valuesIndex < item.Count - 1; valuesIndex++)
            {
                var key = item[valuesIndex];
                string values;
                if(dict.TryGetValue(key, out values))
                {
                    setList(SplitValues(values));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So my thoughts are to integrate a switch / case statement for each name like this

```
case "FACE_OUTER_BOUND":
    // set list for FACE_OUTER_BOUND...
    // ...then call RecursiveMethod(...) again which selects case "EDGE_LOOP" and so on
    break;
```

Does that make sense? Or would I be better off using single methods for each case without recalling the same method?

Comment: Naming your function `RecursiveMethod` is terrible, you should name it based on what the function does. Likewise, the title of your question shouldn't be "using a recursive method" but should actually give a brief description of the problem.

Comment: I used RecursiveMethod(...) just for example purposes
I updated the title

Comment: This looks like [IFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303-21). I would suggest finding a library designed to work with the format instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: Are there any that use C#?
I only find C++ or other langauges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how similar the work will be each time.  If as you navigate down the tree of references you need to perform the same navigation on each branch, recursion's your answer.

If after the first navigation the way you handle branches radically changes, use a separate method.

Very generally speaking, write it to be readable and easy to work with first, then change it if performance becomes an issue or you need to split off the functionality drastically.

Remember also that having a method such as ProbeLinesRecursive(int lineNumber) says something to the programmer who reads it, that is "I'll start with the line you give me, then keep going until I run out of lines to probe".  This kind of descriptive programming becomes hugely helpful the bigger a project becomes over time.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'll try to implement each method seperately and try to create a recursive method afterwards.
It might be even better to first complete the algorithm to get it working instead of infinitely enhancing performance.

Comment: Very true sentiment. At the end of the day, the code is right if it works :)  You can (and no doubt will) end up revisiting it later when other parts of the application are up and running.

Comment: can you upvote my question(if you think it is a good/resonable one)? It seems I am stuck in a "Ask Question Ban" because of having too many questions with 0 upvotes